# Does isset work with GET?

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, isset, server-error

I know this kinda seems like a stupid question and with more research i might be able to find the answer but i have a deadline to please help.

Using codeigniter im trying to see if the 'ID' in the url is 'uID' (user id) or 'sID' (system id).

the code im using is:

```
    if(isset($this->input->get('uID'))) {
        $getID = $this-input->get('uID');
    } else {
        $getID = $this->input->get('sID');
    }
```

when i use that i get a server error saying website is temporarily down or under constrcution. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help. Usually i would spend more time searching for the answer myself but i just dont have time tonight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning you're getting is probably a 500 error -- meaning your server is not set up to display errors to you, or you don't have it enabled in your index.php file.

The error you're getting, but not seeing is: "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context" because you can't use isset on a function.

If you could it wouldn't do what you're expecting as CI's `$this->input->get('key')` always returns a value -- it returns false if the key does not exist.

Therefore, to accomplish what it seems you're trying to do, you'd write:

```
$getID = $this->input->get('uID') ? $this->input->get('uID') : $this->input->get('sID');
```

Based on the comment below, I thought I'd also provide it in a way that makes sense to you:

```
if($this->input->get('uID')) {
  $getID = $this->input->get('uID');
}
else {
  $getID = $this->input->get('sID'):
}
```

The two solutions are functionally the same.

Comment: Ok that works. thanks. I dont understand your code though. whats the '?'

Comment: `condition ? execute_if_the_condition_was_true : exe_if_condition_false` ... called a ternary operator

Comment: is that gonna set $getID to sID if uID isnt set?

Answer (score 2):

`isset` works only on *variables*.
`$this->input->get()` is a *function call*. That gives you an error.

I would guess that if `uID` isn't set in the request, `$this->input->get` will return `null` or `false` or some such. I.e. you don't need `isset`, the return value should already be *falsey*.

I'd recommend you invest the little time it takes to read [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).